# Boost bind object freed on read handler

Tags: sockets, boost-asio, boost-thread

I am using Boost asio to open several sockets I use a collection with shared pointers to a custom class with all that socket info. This class also has the `handle_read` function for `async_receive` as I need to do different things with each receive and I can not bind with extra parameters.

The problem I am having is that when I close the socket I delete the last reference to that pointer so the `handle_read` function is called without any valid reference as this and then the code just breaks.

```
void SocketsAPI::do_close(const SocketInfo socket)
{
    log("do_close");
    if (!socket.m_socket || !socket.m_socket->is_open()) {
        return;
    }   
    boost::system::error_code errorcode;
    socket.m_socket->shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, errorcode);
    if (errorcode) {
        trace("Closing failed: ", errorcode.message());
    }
    socket.m_socket->close(errorcode);
    if (errorcode) {
        trace("Closing2 failed: ", errorcode.message());
    }
    mapType::iterator iter = sockets.find(socket.key);
    if (iter != sockets.end()) {
        sockets.erase (iter);
    }
    log("do_close end");
}
```

Indeed I don't want the `handle_read` function to be called but I am unable to avoid it, and what it is worse in a multithreaded implementation (several threads calling `io_service.run()`) the `handle_read` will be called while the close is still being processed so "this" object will be freed in any point of the handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are close but haven't quite understood the shared ownership semantics that are typically done with applications using the Boost.Asio asynchronous methods. You will want to use `shared_from_this()` when [binding your callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13071142/283302) handlers to ensure they remain in scope for the duration of the async operation. The `io_service::~io_service()` documentation [explains this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4099375/283302) quite nicely.

When you need to stop the async operation prematurely, [cancel it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4546693/283302) rather than closing the socket in your `SocketsAPI::do_close()` method. Then your callback will be given an error code of [`boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/error__basic_errors.html) which you can use to react appropriately.

---

> the `handle_read` will be called while the close is still being
>   processed so "this" object will be freed in any point of the handler.

This is really a separate question, you need to use `strand`s to [ensure exclusive access](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html) to data structures within a handler callback.

Comment: Thanks for the solution it is my first take with Asio and it seems that is really difficult to master. Using shared_from_this works perfectly while using a thread pool I still get a crash while using only 1 thread but probably that is not related the original problem.

Comment: @frisco feel free to ask another question

Comment: the problem is that I am unsure about what is the question :D I am getting a "Microsoft C++ exception: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::thread_resource_error> > at memory location 0x0672f4bc.." but I am not sure when is triggered and VS Debugging isn't helping either.

Comment: @frisco if you tag the question with [tag:visual-c++] and [tag:boost] I'm sure someone will be able to help.